# How to make QTableWidget's columns assume the maximum space?

Tags: python, resize, pyqt, pyqt4, qtablewidget

The columns of my QTableWidget do not fill in the space of the table, so that an empty space is left on the right hand-side. How to make the columns of my QTableWidget assume the maximum space so as to fill in this space?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The [headers](http://doc-snapshot.qt-project.org/4.8/qheaderview.html) of the table have methods for controlling this:

```
header = table.horizontalHeader()
header.setStretchLastSection(True)
```

or:

```
header.setResizeMode(QHeaderView.Stretch)
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of any method to set this property to the QTableWidget's content. However, I could use the following to get the columns to resize:

```
def resizeEvent(self, event):
    self.setColumnWidth(0, event.size().width())
```

This resizes the first column only. To resize all columns, one should get all children item and apply column width / number of items.