# Qt Designer Auto Fitting the tableWidget directly from the Designer

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5, qt-designer

I am trying to auto fit the `tableWidget` columns to the available area of the `tableWidget`

Currently my layout looks like the picture below. As can be seen there is unnecessary white space to the right which I would like to fill out evenly between the four columns.

[image]

Setting `horizontalHeaderStretch` to `True` (shown below) is not what I am after. This stretches the last column unevenly.

[image]

I tried to set the `sizeAdjustPolicy` to `AdjustToCOntents` but I saw no visible difference.

[image]

A similar question can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38098763/pyside-pyqt-how-to-make-set-qtablewidget-column-width-as-proportion-of-the-a), however I couldn't find any mentions on how to do this directly from the designer.

Any suggestions on how this can be done? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The feature you indicate can not be done with Qt Designer. In Qt Designer, only the Q_PROPERTY enabled by the DESIGNABLE flag can be modified, but `setSectionResizeMode()` is not a Q_PROPERTY but a method of QHeaderView, that is indicated in the [docs](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/properties.html#requirements-for-declaring-properties):

> The DESIGNABLE attribute indicates whether the property should be
>   visible in the property editor of GUI design tool (e.g., Qt Designer).
>   Most properties are DESIGNABLE (default true). Instead of true or
>   false, you can specify a boolean member function.

So you'll have to do it programmatically:

```
header = self.table.horizontalHeader()       
header.setSectionResizeMode(0, QtWidgets.QHeaderView.Stretch)
header.setSectionResizeMode(1, QtWidgets.QHeaderView.ResizeToContents)
header.setSectionResizeMode(2, QtWidgets.QHeaderView.ResizeToContents)
# ...
```